# Can't start sql server in single user mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to recover my local sql server's sa password.

I read that I should put it in single user mode, and I did that.

I added the -m; to the startup parameters.

I don't have sql agent running, and I restarted the Sql Server.

When I try:

```
sqlmd -S .\sqlexpress
```

I get the message:

```
Login failed for the user 'mydomain\myuser'. reason: server is in single user mode.
only one administrator can connect at this time.
```

I also tried changing the startup parameter to:

```
-mSQLCMD
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: this would be better answered at ServerFault.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try:

```
NET STOP MSSQLSERVER

… give it a minute … 

NET START MSSQLSERVER /m
```

Comment: Well I have already restarted it many times....and the startup parameters has -m;

Comment: the strange thing though, is when I create a user, I don't see the user in the logins area, and I can't login with it.

Comment: Post a question : http://serverfault.com/ - they might be able to help - I'm not sure why it wouldn't let you back in

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me what basically the same thing but I didn't expect what I should do.

NET STOP [MSSQLSERVERName]

NET START [MSSQLSERVERName] /m /c /f

**No go (But actually this is what worked)**

Now, at first I thought nothing had changed because I got a failure message that the server couldn't be started. I also checked out sql server configuration manager and checked the service status. Where it usually read started or stopped it read pending changes.

**Unexpected Hang**

I couldn't stop or restart the service and thought it was hung so I restarted my computer. It was not until later when I figured out how to fix the problem that I realized that "pending changes" might be the result I wanted to see (I guess, "pending changes" means go fix the problem now).

**Up and running**

I tried the net start command again followed by checking sql configuration manager again -- again "pending changes..."--. But, this time I started up Sql Server Management Studio and I was back in business again, thankfully!

**-c**
Starts SQL Server service independently of the Service Control Manager. Doing so speeds up startup.

**-f**
    This flag starts SQL Server with minimal configuration and allows updates to system tables. This is useful if the DBA has tweaked the configuration options such that the service won't start. If you find yourself in such situation you'll appreciate "-f" flag, since this could be the only way to correct the mistakes in the SQL Server configuration.

**-m**
Starts SQL Server in single-user mode. This means only one user can connect to the server at one time and ad-hoc updates of system tables are allowed. Furthermore, -m option does not start CHECKPOINT. Single-user mode is useful when one of the system databases is corrupt and you have to reload it from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft advises that you should not start sqlserver.exe via command line for anything but a test: "SQL Server should only be started from the command prompt for troubleshooting purposes":

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180965(v=sql.105).aspx

This also advises against using net stop as it leads to unpredictable results.

The solution to reset sa password is to start sql server in single user mode; this is achieved using the -m flag and this should be set via the SQL Server Configuration Manager as advised on MSDN; see step 4 of Step by Step instructions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

If you want to reset the password in SSMS UI then you must *first* tell SQL Configuration Manager that SSMS is the thing that will start SQL Server;

So your -m flag addition to the start of the Startup Parameters on the Advanced tab of SQL Server properties in SQL Congifuration Manager should be (including semi-colon) as follows

–m”Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio – Query”;

If you do not, then you will get a warning in SSMS advising that it cannot login with sa as it is in single user mode.

Remember to remove this startup flag after you are done.

Once in single user mode, you should be able to reset password:
Open SSMS:

1. Expand Security folder
2. Right Click on the sa account
3. Change password

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **all** SQL Server services are stopped except for the **SQL Server instance** itself. I wasted an hour trying to resolve this only to find out that the SQL Server VSS Writer service was running all the time and connecting as soon as the instance starts in single user mode. I had to stop it manually and then was able to login and unlock the sa account.