# How to restore Master db in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

Please can I ask for your assistance in investigating as to why I cannot restore the master db from a recent backup?

Physical copies taken of `.mdf` and `.ldf` master files (just in case!) and then I've recreated a corrupted `master` database by manually deleting content from the `.mdf` file using Notepad to simulate disk corruption.

Subsequently, SQL Server (`MSSQLSERVER`) service will not start which is the scenario I'm trying to resolve.

Actions taken to backup `Master` database:

Prior to corrupting `master`, a backup was taken using following command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE master 
TO DISK = 'C:\Temp\MasterBK.DAT' 
WITH FORMAT, NAME = 'Full Backup of master'
```

Actions taken to restore:

Various different attempts to start SQL Servre service in single-user mode, including:

```
-mSQLCMD 
-m"SQLCMD"
sqlservr.exe -m
NET START MSSQLSERVER /m
```

Tried adding `-m` into Startup Parameters in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Error received on restore

> -mSQLCMD is not a recognised as an internal or external command
>   Service did not start in a timely manner

Version Information:

```
[Windows XP]

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86) 
Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1 <X86> (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please confirm if your backup is right, and then delete the current database (the one which is corrupted).
2. Restore DB using its `.LDF` and `.MDF` physical files:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE DIS 
      ON (FILENAME = 'C:\DIS.mdf'), 
         (FILENAME = 'C:\DIS_1.LDF') 
      FOR ATTACH;
   ```

Please give a try.

For service not running, try to open `windows services` and look for your SQL Server service there or just go SQL Server Configuration Manager.

To run sql server in single user mode, check this post https://mssqlfun.com/2014/09/04/how-to-start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode/.

Your cmd commands might not work because you're not on the right directory where this executables resides.

Comment: Hi, we are unable to start (MSSQLSERVER) service in single user mode in order to run the restore SQL commands. We have tried adding '-m;' into the Startup Parameters field. Starting the service following adding the -m results in the error 'service did not start in a timely manner'. Any ideas?

Comment: @L.Kibbey any errors prompted when trying to access it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708993/cant-start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode try also this commands to force the services

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you go through this link https://campus.barracuda.com/product/backup/article/BBS/RestoreMSSQL2008MasterDB/?welcome-to-campus=techlibrary

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer in the current form. Please avoid posting link-only answers, include the essentials/important parts from the linked resources too. Remote resources are not necessary remain available in the future. Please read [answer] in [help].

Comment: @Pred, I'll try to answer properly next time.